# partial match between files using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to match `$4` in `file2` with a partial string in $1 of `file1` and place the contents `$2` in that file into `$4` of `file2` separated by a `|`.  The problem I am having is that in `file2` the string in `$4` looks like `ADH5_1` and its match in `file1` `$1` looks like `426_238486_128(ADH5)_1_1`. I am not sure how to best approach this.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
426_238486_128(ADH5)_1_1 70
426_238487_128(ADH5)_2_1 50.83
426_238488_128(ADH5)_3.1_1 46.67
```

**file2**

```
chr4    100009839   100009851   ADH5_1
chr4    100006265   100006367   ADH5_2
chr4    100003125   100003267   ADH5_3
```

**desired output**

```
chr4    100009839   100009851   ADH5_1|70
chr4    100006265   100006367   ADH5_2|50.83
chr4    100003125   100003267   ADH5_3|46.67
```

I know that a partial match in `awk` can be done but not sure how to do it on an entire file rather than a keyword and also how to format the string so it can be searched correctly.

```
awk '$1 ~ /AGRN_1/ { print }' file1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR{split($1,t,/[_().]+/); a[t[4]"_"t[5]]=$NF; next} {print $0, a[$NF]}' file1 file2
chr4    100009839   100009851   ADH5_1|70
chr4    100006265   100006367   ADH5_2|50.83
chr4    100003125   100003267   ADH5_3|46.67
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an awk script like this (tested with GNU Awk):

```
FNR==NR { # file 1
    # extract key from $1
    k = gensub( /^.*\(([^)]+)\)_([0-9]+).*$/, "\\1_\\2", 1, $1 )
    m[ k ] = $2 # store value $2 from file1
    next # line (of file1)
    }

    # file2
    {
    print $0 "|" m[$4]
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

The first block after `FNR==NR` is executed for the first file, the `next` takes care that the second block is not reached for the first file.  This block calculates a key (in the format of the second file) and stores the value under the key.

The second block is only executed for the second file, it looks up the value and prints the desired line.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

remove the parenthesis and look for a match

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{sub(/\(/,"");sub(/\)/,""); a[$1]=$2; next}
     {for(k in a) {if(k~$4) {print $0, a[k]; next}}}' file1 file2

chr4    100009839   100009851   ADH5_1 70
chr4    100006265   100006367   ADH5_2 50.83
chr4    100003125   100003267   ADH5_3 46.67
```

for pipe delimiter, set `-v OFS='|'`